# Electron Get file path from form and display as text

Tags: html, electron

I am creating a simple program in Electron. The program has the option of running several separate functions based on  what the user needs. All functions require a file to be inputted and a save location for the resulting output file. This is done using a form. I would like to have it that once the user inputs the locations it is displayed in a div beside the input buttons. Is there a way to do this within electron?

code:

```
<!-- File Input Section -->
                <div class = "individual-input-container-2">
                    <div class="input-container" >
                        <div class = "inner-input-container">
                            <input type="file" id="file-input" class = "input-top" >
                            <p class = "input-desc-file">File</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-container">
                        <div class = "inner-input-container">
                            <input type="file" webkitdirectory  id="save-input"class = "input-bottom">
                            <p class = "input-desc-save">Save Location</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Here is photo of what I am building

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try Electron's `dialog.showSaveDialog ()`/[`dialog.showSaveDialogSync ()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogsyncbrowserwindow-options) functions. They return a `Promise<string>` or a string representing the file/folder which was selected by the user, respectively. Then you can easily display in your `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a while back and mine looks like this:

HTML:

```html
<button id="choosePath">Choose Folder</button>
```

JS:

```
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;

document.querySelector('#choosePath').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({
        title:"Select Directory",
        properties: ["openDirectory"]
    }, (folderPaths) => {
        // folderPaths is an array that contains all the selected paths
        if(folderPaths === undefined){
            return;
        } else {
            // Do something with the folderPaths variable
        }
    });
});
```

It's basically just an ordinary button opening a Dialog Window where you can select a path.
If you did select one the full Path is passed to a callback function where you can use it to do whatever you have to do with it.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I am very new to electron so not quite sure what is happening here but you have given me a good jumping off point!

Comment: Yeah, so it's basically the Electron equivalent to the `<input type="file">` HTML Element. If you need further Infos on how to use it you can also check the [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog) .